Power BI Rest API, Activity Log, audit/tracking data, activity events
I'm trying to get information about user activity in Power BI Service:

What report each user is viewed for given time range (or all period, let's say)
when is viewed
how much time is viewed
what visuals they export
and so on

Firstly, I just want to get information about users who viewed report and I'm getting an error
I was able to get access token, fetch logs
however, getting the next error message:
Access Token JSON: {'token_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_in': 3599, 'ext_expires_in': 3599, 'access_token': 'eyJ0eXAi.........'}
Fetching logs from 2024-06-11T00:00:00.000Z to 2024-06-11T23:59:59.999Z
Requesting logs with URL: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime=2024-06-11T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&endDateTime=2024-06-11T23%3A59%3A59.999Z
Response Status Code: 400
HTTP error occurred: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime=2024-06-11T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&endDateTime=2024-06-11T23%3A59%3A59.999Z
Response text: {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Bad Request","details":[{"message":"Object must implement IConvertible.","target":"startDateTime"},{"message":"Object must implement IConvertible.","target":"endDateTime"}]}}

   import requests
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus, unquote, quote
    # Constants (Replace these with your actual values)
    CLIENT_ID = '-------------------'
    TENANT_ID = '-------------------'
    CLIENT_SECRET = '-----------------'
    # Get access token using Microsoft identity platform (v2.0; MSAL)
    def get_access_token():
    url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    body = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'scope': 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
    response.raise_for_status()
    token_json = response.json()
    print("Access Token JSON:", token_json)  # Debugging output
    return token_json.get('access_token')
    # Fetch activity logs
    def fetch_activity_logs(access_token, start_datetime, end_datetime, continuation_token=None):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }
    params = {
        'startDateTime': start_datetime,
        'endDateTime': end_datetime
    }
    if continuation_token:
        params['continuationToken'] = unquote(continuation_token)
    
    url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?{urlencode(params)}"
    
    print(f"Requesting logs with URL: {url}")  # Debugging output
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(f"Response Status Code: {response.status_code}")
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()
    # Main script
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        access_token = get_access_token()
        # Set the date range for a single day (yesterday) in the required format
        yesterday = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        start_datetime = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z")
        end_datetime = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59.999Z")
        print(f"Fetching logs from {start_datetime} to {end_datetime}")  # Debugging output
        # Initialize an empty list to hold all logs
        all_logs = []
        continuation_token = None
        # Loop to handle pagination
        while True:
        logs = fetch_activity_logs(access_token, start_datetime, end_datetime,                                                continuation_token)
            all_logs.extend(logs.get('activityEventEntities', []))
            
            # Check for continuation token
            continuation_token = logs.get('continuationToken')
            if continuation_token:
                print(f"Continuation Token: {continuation_token}")  # Debugging output
                continuation_token = continuation_token
            else:
                break  # Exit loop if no continuation token is provided
        # Print the raw logs to understand the structure
        print("Raw logs:", all_logs)
        # Extract relevant data and create a DataFrame
        data = []
        for log in all_logs:
            if log.get('Activity') == 'ViewReport':  # Filter for 'ViewReport' activity type
                user = log.get('UserId')
                report = log.get('ItemName')
                start_time = log.get('CreationTime')
                data.append({'User': user, 'Report': report, 'StartTime': start_time})  
        # Create a DataFrame
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df) 
        # Optionally save to CSV
        df.to_csv('powerbi_viewreport_logs_today_filtered.csv', index=False)
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {err}")
        print(f"Response text: {err.response.text}")
        except Exception as err:
        print(f"An error occurred: {err}")`


You have to make sure that your start date and end date parameters are formatted correctly. Maybe this piece of code can help you:
startDateTime = start_date.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds').replace('+00:00', 'Z')

endDateTime = end_date.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds').replace('+00:00', 'Z')


Hi, to help people understand your answer, i highly recommend to explain the code a bit more
